# Xamarin Forms Picker Cascading

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am involved in a project where I am stuck in the following situation:
I have a picker (dropdown) where it needs to display a second picker based on first selected item from the first picker (Cascading). Values are dynamic (from Sqlite tables).
Here you have my codes:

XAML

```
 Picker 1
    <Picker x:Name="picker" Title="Select Country" SelectedIndexChanged="OnModeChosen">
    Picker 2
    <Picker x:Name="picker2" Title="Select Regions" IsEnabled="False">
```

Models

```
public class Country
        {
          [PrimaryKey]
          Public int CountryId {get;set;}
          public string CountryName {get;set;}

          public Country(){}
        }

        public class Regions
        {
          [PrimaryKey]
          public int RegionsId {get; set;}
          public string RegionsName {get;set;}
          [ForeignKey(typeof(Country))]
          public int CountryId {get;set;}

          public Regions(){}
        }
```

// Code Behind

```
private void OnModeChosen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Picker modePicker = (Picker)sender;
    var mode = picker.SelectedIndex;
    picker2.Items.Clear();

         switch(mode)
         {
           //This is the part I would like dynamic
         }
     }
```

I would like the handler "OnModeChosen" to work dynamically (any selected value from picker 1 will display the according values of picker 2). By the way, I would appreciate any other approach, as I am interested in having the expected result.
Thanks for your support guys.
I am working on this for hours and can't find anything worth it on internet.

Comment: I got a similar thing solved, mine one involves that you have to pick a house first and that it fills up the other picker with appartements, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solved it in my project:

```
  private void OnModeChosen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Country country = ((Country)(picker.SelectedItem)) // get the country object from  the picker
          picker2.ItemsSource =  GetRegions(country.CountryId ) // call the function to get the regions for that country
          picker2.ItemDisplayBinding = New Binding("RegionsName")
          picker2.SelectedIndex = 0 // not sure why I did this, I think to make sure an item was selected
        stackpicker2.IsVisible = true // make the stack layout visible with the 2nd picker
        picker2.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi  Jordy, I could not implement your answer,  is this the whole code for OnModeChosen? I am still stuck

Comment: at line 2 I call a function GetRegions, this one you have to make yourself. Here you pass the idd of the country and use that id to get the regions out of your sqllite database, if that wasn't it, what you stuck at?

Comment: ps just noticed that u disabled ur picker2 don't forget to enable it, I added it to ym code

Comment: sorry Jordy, your code didn't work for me, still stuck.

Comment: At which part are you stuck?

Comment: you say for instance, Country country = ((Country)(e.item)) to get object from picker 1, e.item does not work

Comment: That's weird, could you show the code of how you filled up picker1?

Comment: so ((Country)(e.item))  pulls out the item that you picked from picker1. This is (normally) an object of the type Country. From this object I request the id so that I request all the regions that have connection with that id. Those regions I use to fill  up the itemsource for picker2. With itemdisplaybinding i tell the picker what value it needs to show ( here I ask the name) and the rest you can read next to the program lines. is there something that you don't comprehend ? don't hesistate to ask

Comment: I swapped e.item by picker.selecteditem which normally does the same but it's a bit better to comprehend

Comment: Hi Jordy, thanks for your support. It finally worked as I struggling with the GetRegions method, I sorted it out and worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey! Anyone get this to work 100% with a ViewModel and two way binding (without hacking the code behind?)

Comment: Depends on what you mean without hacking the code behind?

Comment: @JordyDieltjens I mean without manually setting things in the SelectedIndexChanged event. ie. Using bindings in Xaml. Dynamically adding bindings in events during code-behind, seems like a slippery slope for a simple cascading picker solution. BTW: I did figure out how to do this. As well as binding the visibility of the Secondary/Cascaded pickers via visibilityConverter binding.